# How to redirect STDOUT to a NSTextView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, stdout

Could anybody show me how to redirect the Stdout to a NSTextView?

and whether the info print by NSLog belong to the std?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

The code below uses `dup2` to plug stdout onto the write-end of an `NSPipe` object. The read-end is observed with a GCD dispatch source, that reads data from the pipe and appends it to a textview.

```
NSPipe* pipe = [NSPipe pipe];
NSFileHandle* pipeReadHandle = [pipe fileHandleForReading];
dup2([[pipe fileHandleForWriting] fileDescriptor], fileno(stdout));
dispatch_source_t source = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_READ, [pipeReadHandle fileDescriptor], 0, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0));
dispatch_source_set_event_handler(source, ^{
    void* data = malloc(4096);
    ssize_t readResult = 0;
    do
    {
        errno = 0;
        readResult = read([pipeReadHandle fileDescriptor], data, 4096);
    } while (readResult == -1 && errno == EINTR);
    if (readResult > 0)
    {
        //AppKit UI should only be updated from the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
            NSString* stdOutString = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytesNoCopy:data length:readResult encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding freeWhenDone:YES];
            NSAttributedString* stdOutAttributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stdOutString];
            [self.logView.textStorage appendAttributedString:stdOutAttributedString];
        });
    }
    else{free(data);}
});
dispatch_resume(source);
```

`NSLog(@"...")` does not output to `stdout` though - It prints to `stderr`. If you want to redirect that into your textview, change

```
dup2([[pipe fileHandleForWriting] fileDescriptor], fileno(stdout));
```

to

```
dup2([[pipe fileHandleForWriting] fileDescriptor], fileno(stderr));
```

Comment: This may be a dumb question but: if NSPipe is already buffered (by its own implementation or else by the OS construct which it wraps), then why is it necessary to define your own data buffer?

Comment: You are right NSPipe is buffered by default (from the docs "... the pipe is buffered; the size of the buffer is determined by the underlying operating system..."). But it still might be a good idea to read in chunks, to have finer grained control about memory consumption within your own process. (Sounds like the pipe's buffer is maintained by the OS)

Comment: Also, is it possible the `do` loop is incorrectly testing for error or termination conditions rather than the absence of those conditions?

Comment: The while loop does not control the iteration over the available data. It just handles the very unlikely case where an interrupt signal is sent. The dispatch source handler is called multiple times when the available data is larger than the buffer size.

Comment: As *NSPipe*,*NSFileHandle* and *dup2* are available in iOS ...we can safely assume it will work for iOS too right !

Comment: The above code doesen't work if you don't have Xcode debugging your app. This post identifies why and how to fix it. (I,e. the buffering issues someone alluded to here). https://stackoverflow.com/a/54124239/516661

Answer (score 1):

I know the question was about objective-c but I thought I would post a swift answer incase that helps someone else.

```
let pipefd = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int32>.allocate(capacity: 8)
pipe(pipefd)

dup2(pipefd[1], fileno(stdout))

// Print something here

let buf = UnsafeMutableRawPointer.allocate(byteCount: 1024, alignment: 0)
read(pipefd[0], buf, 100)

close(pipefd[1])

let output = self.ptrToString(pointer: buf)
if output != "" {
    // Do something with output
}

buf.deallocate()
pipefd.deallocate()
```

And here is the function I use to convert the pointer to a string:

```
func ptrToString (pointer buf: UnsafeMutableRawPointer) -> String {
    let filteredArray = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: buf.assumingMemoryBound(to: UInt8.self), count: 1024)).filter { item in
        return item != 0
    }

    return filteredArray
        .map { String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8($0))) }
        .joined()
        .components(separatedBy: "\n")[0]
}
```

Works on swift 4

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution, this example uses a NSTask and makes a NSString

```
NSError * hala;
NSTask * nettask = [[NSTask alloc] init];
nettask.executableURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file:/usr/sbin/networksetup"];
nettask.arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"-listlocations"];
NSPipe * piper = [NSPipe pipe];
nettask.standardOutput = piper;
NSFileHandle * pipereader = [piper fileHandleForReading];
[nettask launchAndReturnError:&hala];
if (hala) printf ("taskproblem %s\n", hala.description.UTF8String);
[nettask waitUntilExit];
if ([nettask terminationStatus]) printf ("task did not end successfully\n");
else {
    NSData * readout = [pipereader readDataToEndOfFileAndReturnError:&hala];
    if (hala) printf ("readproblem %s\n", hala.description.UTF8String);
    NSString * result = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:readout.bytes length:readout.length - 1 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];  //skip trailing \n
}
```

Answer (score -1):

if the goal is to handle your NSLog output only, not the system generated error logs, there is an other way to do so, here is a code to overclass NSLog. This code is only printing the log and some extra information on stderr instead of the usual NSLog output, but you can make any changes that suites your needs inside the HyperLog function :

HyperLog.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#ifdef HYPER_LOG
#define NSLog(args...) HyperLog(__FILE__,__LINE__,__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,args);
#else
#define NSLog(x...)
#endif

void HyperLog(const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *functionName, NSString *format, ...);
```

Hyperlog.m

```
#import "HyperLog.h"

void HyperLog(const char *file, int lineNumber, const char *functionName, NSString *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    va_start (ap, format);
    if (![format hasSuffix: @"\n"])
    {
        format = [format stringByAppendingString: @"\n"];
    }

    NSString *body = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:format arguments:ap];
    va_end (ap);
     NSString *fileName = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:file] lastPathComponent];
    char mesg[8192]="\0";
    NSDate *now =[NSDate date];
    NSString *dateString = [NSDateFormatter localizedStringFromDate:now dateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle timeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
    if ( sprintf( mesg, "<%s.%03.0f> : %s\n<%s : %d - %s>\n", [dateString UTF8String],roundf(fmod( [now timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate], 1 ) * 1000), [body UTF8String], [fileName UTF8String],
                 lineNumber,
            functionName) < 0 ) printf("message creation failed\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", mesg );
}
```

You then only need to put these 2 lines on top of any of your program file
to have it work

```
#define HYPER_LOG
#import "HyperLog.h"
```

I tried to use the above code from Thomas to have the result data of a system generated error log written to a text file using a C function, that works properly in other contexts, but it keeps and crashing, and the error reason is lost in the process. Anyone has an idea why ?