# Redirect print to a File like redirecting NSLog to a file

Tags: ios, swift, nslog

I have redirected *NSLog* to a *file* using the macros.

But I couldn't find a stable way in swift to do that.

As of now I am doing a workaround

I define the following method so whenever I call print in the file it comes here and I write that to a file.

```
func print(log:String!) {
        if let logg = log {
            DeveloperConsoleManager.sharedInstance.writeOnConsoleLog(logg)
        }
    }
```

But problems with this approach are

1.I will get **Extra Argument in Call**
If I do like below

```
print("some comments",Obj1,Obj2)
```

so I have to use like this

```
print("some comments \(Obj1) \(Obj2)")
```

2.I will get error like **Cannot convert value of type '[AnyObject]' to expected argument type 'String!'** If I try to print an object directly

```
print(obj)
```

so I have to call the description method of the object

```
print(obj.description)
```

3.*I have to include the function definition that I have quoted above wherever I want this functionality But in the case of NSLog its globally defined in one place*

so Now I am looking for a stable solution to *redirect the contents of **print** in swift to a file*

so I can use ***print*** as I do normally in swift

*Update:*

I tried overriding the print but I got  **Method does not override any method from its superclass**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, overriding `NSLog` with a macro is really bad approach. Just use a different function name and use that. Overriding `print` is even more fragile. Just name it something else. When someone sees `NSLog` or `print` in the code, it shouldn't be a trick.

That said, it'll generally work within a given module, as long as you give it the right signature:

```
public func print(items: Any..., separator: String = "", terminator: String = "\n")
```

(EDIT: Fixed up the signature to be very explicit on exactly how `print` does it, rather than just showing the docs.)

You didn't use varargs syntax (`...`) in your function, which is why it doesn't accept multiple parameters. And if you want it to accept non-Strings (like `obj`) then you have to accept `Any`, not just `String`.

If you just make your own `printlog` function (or whatever you want to call it), then of course you can use whatever signature is convenient, but if you're going to overload `print`, you'll need to match its signature and functionality.

Here's the full implementation. This is a terrible way to do it. You should not override `print`. But this is how Swift allows it to be done (spread across three files just to demonstrate that it's working):

main.swift:

```
func print(items: Any..., separator: String = "", terminator: String = "\n") {
    Swift.print("My print is printing \(items)", separator: separator, terminator: terminator)
}

print("In main!")
file1print()
file2print()
```

file1.swift:

```
func file1print() {
    print("file1!") // Calls our print
}
```

file2.swift:

```
func file2print() {
    print("file2!") // Calls our print
}
```

Again, this is a horrible idea. It is far better, flexible, and clearer to just create a new function. But Swift definitely can do it.

As a note, if your real goal is just to write stdout or stderr to a file, there's no need to override print or NSLog this way. Just reopen your stdout and/or stderr. For example:

```
let path: NSString = ...;
freopen(path.UTF8String, "a+", stderr)
```

That would redirect stderr. Use stdout to get stdout. This will work for anything that prints to stdout/err, no matter what module does it.

Comment: How to create a global function like print ? any ideas ? probably create a category of super class that all classes acquire and call that right !

Comment: Put it outside any class or struct. They're called "free functions."

Comment: My idea is somehow override the print in swift and stick with that... I tried to override  like `override func print(_: Any..., separator: String, terminator: String)` i get Method does not override any method from its superclass...If you could guide me to achieve this it'd be helpful a lot.

Comment: Don't use `override`. You're just replacing it in this module or any module that imports this module. Keep in mind that when it's missing (for instance in a module that doesn't import this one), you'll get no warning about that. The other `print` will be found instead. That's the problem with using the same name.

Comment: Just once for the module. By default its access level is internal.

Comment: the print function can't be used like free function and I can't put the function definition in one class and inherit in all the places because Multiple inheritance problem will come.so I have to copy paste the print function in all the places I want like appdelegate,viewcontroller ...etc..

Comment: How to call free functions of swift in Objective C ? I marked the free function with public also but I couldn't access it in the Objective C.

Comment: @DuraiAmuthan.H Make them static methods inside of a class that ObjC can see. Free functions are not exported from Swift to ObjC.

Comment: I put that inside the function also but As I am using varargs in the function it is not accessible I guess public func print(logs:AnyObject!...)

Comment: Swift methods that include variadics cannot be exposed to ObjC. See https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH4-ID35

Answer (score 2):

If I dare go off at a tangent...

The safest way to redirect `NSLog` is to redirect its *output* rather than trying to catch people providing it with input.

The answer to [How to redirect STDOUT to a NSTextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16391279/how-to-redirect-stdout-to-a-nstextview) is an appropriate place to start — `NSPipe`, `NSFileHandle` and `dup2` are all also available on iOS.

Comment: For *NSLog* its `stderr` but for `print` in swift ... is it `stderr` too ?

Comment: Despite Apple being unwilling to specify more than "an appropriate output", I _think_ `print` currently and empirically prints to `stdout`.