# Swift stdout redirect to a string

Tags: swift, pipe, stdout

I'm trying to redirect stdout to a string with Swift, to collect whatever is passed to the `print` function. I've read through a few resources that suggest my approach should be working, however, the following proof of concept script only outputs "Starting":

```swift
import Foundation

let outPipe = Pipe()
var outString = "Initial"
outPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { fileHandle in
    outString += String(data: fileHandle.availableData, encoding: .utf8)!
}
print("Starting")

// Redirect
setvbuf(stdout, nil, _IONBF, 0)
dup2(outPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO)

print("Captured")
freopen("/dev/stdout", "a", stdout)
print(outString)
```

Any ideas where I've gone wrong? All help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm guessing [this](https://phatbl.at/2019/01/08/intercepting-stdout-in-swift.html) was what you found?

Comment: @Sweeper Correct, along with [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978091/using-pipe-in-swift-app-to-redirect-stdout-into-a-textview-only-runs-in-simul)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the pipe's read handler is called on a secondary queue, but your program does not have a run loop. Therefore the program terminates before the event handler is called once.

In a command line application, one option so solve this is with a “dispatch semaphore” which is signaled in the event handler, once it detect an end-of-file condition on the pipe. And in order to make this work, we must *close* the writing end of the pipe eventually.

Also the standard output file descriptor should be saved and restored later. Reopening "/dev/stdout" will not work if the program is run in the Xcode debugger console.

The following code produces the expected output. It is meant as a “proof of concept” example. In your production code you'll want to avoid things like a forced `try!`.

```swift
import Foundation

let outPipe = Pipe()
var outString = "Initial"
let sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)
outPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { fileHandle in
    let data = fileHandle.availableData
    if data.isEmpty  { // end-of-file condition
        fileHandle.readabilityHandler = nil
        sema.signal()
    } else {
        outString += String(data: data,  encoding: .utf8)!
    }
}
print("Starting")

// Redirect
setvbuf(stdout, nil, _IONBF, 0)
let savedStdout = dup(STDOUT_FILENO)
dup2(outPipe.fileHandleForWriting.fileDescriptor, STDOUT_FILENO)

print("Captured")

// Undo redirection
dup2(savedStdout, STDOUT_FILENO)
try! outPipe.fileHandleForWriting.close()
close(savedStdout)
sema.wait() // Wait until read handler is done

print(outString) // Prints "InitialCaptured"
```